# django uwsgi logto function not work in docker

Tags: django, docker, uwsgi

dockerizing a django app with uwsgi

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /app
http = :12345
socket=127.0.0.1:8002
wsgi-file=leak/wsgi.py
static-map = /static=static
processes=4
threads=2
master=True
log-master = true
threaded-logger = true
logto=/var/log/leak.log
log-maxsize = 100000
threaded-logger = true
pidfile=uwsgi.pid
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=leak.settings.development
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6.8-alpine
COPY requirements /app/requirements
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update 
        && apk add make \
        && apk add --virtual mysqlclient-build gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
        && apk add --no-cache mariadb-dev \
        && apk add --virtual system-build linux-headers libffi-dev \
        && apk add --no-cache jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
        && apk add --no-cache bash bash-doc bash-completion libxml2-dev libxslt-dev \
        && pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel \
        && pip install -r requirements
COPY . /app 
CMD ["sh","run.sh"]
```

**run.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

after docker build && docker run the logpath "/var/log/leak.log" not create and without any errors.
but its worked without docker.
how can i fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few suggestions:

- do not run uwsgi as root
- `threaded-logger = true` is defined 2 times
- log under `/app/log`, and mount it as a volume, with the proper permissions for the user
- alpine images can run `#!/bin/sh`

regards, matzy